# Call view with modified environ from within other view

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app that has two blueprints, an API and a web frontend.  I want to call a function in the API blueprint from the frontend blueprint, but with a different context, specifically I want to change the `HTTP_ACCEPT` environment variable, then restore the original request for further handling.

When I use either `ctx.push()` / `ctx.pop()x` or `with app.request_context(request.environ)` the environment variable doesn't change back to the original.

```
@dashboard_blueprint.route('/station', methods=['GET'])
def station():
    station_id = request.args['id']

    print(request.environ['HTTP_ACCEPT'])
    # >>> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

    with app.request_context(request.environ) as ctx:
        ctx.request.environ['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/vnd.geo+json'
        # Call API function here.

    print(request.environ['HTTP_ACCEPT'])
    # >>> application/vnd.geo+json
...
```

I expect the second `print()` to print the original `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8` but it instead prints `application/vnd.geo+json` from the inner context.

I could store the original value and restore it after using the inner context, but that seems unnecessary.  Why isn't the environ restored after the context is popped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask doesn't copy the data you pass to `request_context`.  If you pass an existing environment, that will be used (and modified) in place.  Pass a copy instead.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(request.environ['HTTP_ACCEPT'])

    new_environ = request.environ.copy()
    new_environ['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'test'

    with app.request_context(new_environ):
        print(request.environ['HTTP_ACCEPT'])

    print(request.environ['HTTP_ACCEPT'])
    return 'Hello, World!'

app.run()
```

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
test
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```